# add service (injected) inside automapper

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, automapper

i'm working in .net core 
adding automapper in startup like

```
    services.AddAutoMapper(AutomapperHelper.GetProfileTypes());
```

is it possibile to inject/add some services/objects inside automapper profiles inside CreateMap() ?!

and use it or pass to mapped objects, inside mapping profiles ...

i would not like to use opt.Items during .Map()

P.S. i was loosing time looking ConstructServicesUsing() but it looks like designed for creating relovers and type converter

Comment: Profiles are singletons and don't support DI to avoid misuse. But that doesn't stop you from implementing that if you must have it.

Comment: i really don't know how...
i'm "forced" to use option.items (that i really don't like)

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#dependency-injection